# How macro could be used to calculate offset of fields in a structure?

Tags: c, struct, macros

I have defined a macro that calculates the offset of a structure to any of the structure field. The Code is as follow:

```
#define offset(struct_name, fld_name) \
(unsigned int)&(((struct_name *)0)->fld_name)

typedef struct emp_{
   char name[20];
   unsigned int salary;
   char designation[30];
   unsigned int emp_id;
} emp_t;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    unsigned int offsetValue;
    offsetValue=offset(emp_t,salary);
    printf("field = %s\n","salary");
    printf("offset = %d\n", offsetValue);
    return 0;
}
```

how exactly the `#define offset` macro is calculating the offset? What is `&(((struct_name *)0)->fld_name)` actually doing? The outer `&` denote the address but what exactly remaining `(((struct_name *)0)->fld_name)` means?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? The macro you're trying implement is already part of the C89/C99 standard. It's `offsetof(type, member)`, defined in `stddef.h`.

Comment: It's a "trick". It's getting the _address_ of the [given] field. It's converting the _address_ value to an `unsigned int`. Because the base address of the given `struct` is `0`, the calculated/returned address is _equivalent_ to the offset of the field within the struct.